# originalentity cannot be specified for an insert operation

Tags: entity-framework, ria

I'm currently working with Silverlight and the RIA services Entity Framework. Today I have encountered an error message saying "invalid changeset: originalentity cannot be specified for an insert operation". I Googled with no result, so my question is: has anyone ever encountered the same problem?
Here are the steps to reproduce the error:

- create a new entity and add it to its entity set
- submit changes
- remove the entity
- submit changes
- add again the entity to the entity set
- submit changes -> the error shows up here

Since the status of the entity is "new", my hypothesis is that the framework is trying to perform an insert operation, but the data that is passed to the server side still has some information on the entity as it was inserted before (the "originalentity", which is probably meant to be used in update operations), so the insert operation fails. What do you think?

Comment: I am encountering the same issue as you are. Were you able to fix this as this was posted long time ago?

Comment: I usually solve this kind of problem by clearing the entity set or by manually detaching the conflicting elements and then fetching them again from the DB, so that entity collections do not contain old objects. I also make sure I always use LoadBehavior.RefreshCurrent in my queries, so that existing entities are overwritten.